# What is the importance and Application of studying degree of commutativity in finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

What are the application and importance (or significance) of studying commutativity degree in a finite group $G$. i.e Significance of finding probability  that arbitrary chosen element of the group commutes?

Comment: Probabilities on groups, like commutativity degree etc., give intuitions about the structure of the groups. In case of commutativity degree $d(G)$ of a group $G$, it is equivalent to count the number $k(G)$ of conjugacy classes of the group $G$. Indeed, $d(G)=k(G)/|G|$.

Comment: I find it rather striking that, if the commutativity degree of a finite group is $>\frac{5}{8}$, then the group is abelian. For generalizations to infinite groups, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.05565.pdf